# bounded input, bounded state stability in reverse

Tags: matrices

I have a stable, linear, time-invariant system with state space representation (A, B, C, $0$).  I have established that the state remains bounded, i.e. $x \in \mathcal{L}_{\infty}$. Ironically I have not been able to establish that the input $u(t)$ remains bounded, though I have established that $u \in \mathcal{L}_{2}$.  If we restrict ourselves to input signals that are continuous, is it possible to have an unbounded input produce a bounded state in this situation?  I've been trying to think of this from the perspective of the solution to the LTI state space dynamics equation:
\begin{equation}
x(t) = e^{At}x(0)+\int_0^te^{A(t-\tau)}Bu(\tau)d\tau
\end{equation}
I would appreciate any reference suggestions that might help me better understand the situation.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot prove that $u$ is bounded. A simple counterexample:
$$\dot{x}=-x+u(t)$$
with 
$$u(t)=\delta(t-1)$$
and $\delta(\cdot)$ the Dirac delta function.
Bounded $x$ with unbounded $u$.

**Edit:** More generally for a stable $A$, the state $x$ will be bounded if $u$ 
$$\int_0^\infty \|u(t)\|dt<\infty$$
There are many unbounded continuous functions that satisfy the above property.

Comment: $x(t)$ is most certainly bounded.  I have established this separately via Lyapunov stability techniques.  $u(t)$ arises from an adaptive control law...thus the disconnect.  So putting it more succinctly, I would like to know if a bounded input is a necessary condition for a bounded state.

Comment: Yes this is exactly what the above example shows. Bounded $x$ even though $u(t)=\delta(t-1)$ is unbounded. Thus, it does not work both ways.

Comment: Let's say that $u(t)$ is continuous.  I've edited my post accordingly.

Comment: Even continuous is not enough. I think what you are after is $u$ to be uniformly continuous.